# Why must I put OR between each number in a long query string?

Tags: solr, lucene

Typically when you query a string Solr will tokenize everything and find all word matches in a document no problem.  However I ran into an interesting issue that took me a couple of hours to figure out.

Say for example I have a document with a field (fieldtype: text_ws) called "ids" which contains the following string.

```
23 128 150 250 384 582 583 586 587 589 641 713 745 761 1004 1040 1080 1512 1551 1626 1882 1891 1911 1912 1913 1947 2035 2120 2140 2141 2143 2176 2219 2430 3023 3041 4087 4221 4243 4737 4776 5126 5130 5194 5224 5225 5226 5555 5564 5565 5568 5611 6310 9984 12048 12143 12878 12929 12930 12931 12933 12935 14001 14048 14049 14051 14079 14080 14082 14083
```

Now if I queried against that field with the following it would only match the first digit.  However if I put OR between each one then it would match almost all of them as it should.

```
23 128 150 250 384 582 583 586 587 589 641 713 745 761 1004 1040 1512 1551 1626 1703 1760 1882 1891 1911 1913 1947 2035 2120 2140 2141 2143 2176 2219 2430 3023 3041 4087 4221 4243 4737 4776 5126 5130 5194 5224 5225 5226 5555 5564 5565 5568 5611 6310 9984 12048 12143 12878 12929 12930 12931 12933 12935 14001 14048 14049 14051 14079 14080 14082 14083
```

What's the deal with this?

Additionally, how can I prevent Solr from boosting scores?  What if I just want to know what percentage of the items from the query matched?

text_ws definition

```
<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of your `test_ws` field from your `schema.xml`?

Comment: Look like some value is ignored? Try to make field stored, to see how the doc actually look like.

Comment: @Fuxi - The field is index and stored.  Maybe I am misunderstanding your suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are querying -
e.g. `q=ids:23 128`, only the field ids is queried for 23 while the default search field mentioned in schema.xml (usually text) is queried for 128.
Query formed is `ids:23 text:128`, so only the ids would be queried for the first term and the rest would be queried on the default text field.

How are you querying with OR ? If q=ids:(23 OR 128), it would match the entire ids field.

You can use the debugQuery parameter to check the query created by Solr.

Comment: I discovered that it was falling back on the default field while going through the debugQuery.  My solution was q=ids:23 OR ids:128, so what you mentioned is much readable, but I need to ensure that I can add a boost to them as well.  If I wanted to add a boost to a particular field would it have to be on each query term q=ids:(23^2 OR 128^2) or can I do something like q=ids:(23 OR 128)^2?

Comment: What I am doing is actually querying a bunch of ID numbers on that ids field, but also needing to compare text to another field at the same time. I would prefer that the IDs had more impact than the word matches on the other field.